# How to use 'Replace' function in SalesForce SOAP API in C#

Tags: c#, api, soap, salesforce

I am using SalesForce SOAP Enterprise WSDL API in my C# application.
What I came across is the need to use the `SELECT` query which includes `REPLACE` function.
I tried Developer Console>>Query Editor by executing the following query, but it's giving me 
`Unknown error parsing query` error.

Following is my query that I want to execute :

`SELECT Id, Name, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, office_phone__c.replace("-",""), phone_fax__c FROM Contact`

I also tried in the following way, but that's also giving me the same error.

`SELECT Id, Name, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, REPLACE(office_phone__c,'-',''), phone_fax__c FROM Contact`

As the query implies, I want to replace `"-"` in my `office_phone__c` field with `""`.

Has anyone used such type of query before.
I would be very grateful if anybody can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL doesn't support functions in select clause (other than aggregates). You'll need to either create a formula field for your function and select that instead, or do the processing on the client once you've fetched the data.

Comment: That's pretty poor. I was using SugarCRM earlier and now we need to migrate to SalesForce. In terms of these aggregate functions, SugarCRM is richer than SalesForce. May be some of these updates get available in the future releases. Thanks..!